# Renaming columns in SAS by removing names before

Tags: sas

Im quite new to SAS and I had a table with table names as such:

```
ID shoe.description shoe.color shoe.size shoe.reviews shoe.price store URL
```

I plan to create a function to rename the variables without shoe into something like

```
ID description color size reviews price store URL
```

May i know how could I be able to do it?

Comment: Are you asking about variable names or dataset names?  Normal SAS naming rules do not allow names to include periods.  Are you sure your variable names include those periods? What does the output of PROC CONTENTS run on your dataset show as the names of the variables?

Comment: Im refering to dataset names. I'm trying to avoid using 'shoe.description'n that why im wondering how could i drop 'shoe.' from the column names

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list of variable names to help you generate the RENAME statement.

First get the list of variables into a dataset.  For example by using PROC CONTENTS.

```
proc contents data=have noprint out=contents; run;
```

If the number of variables is not unreasonably large then you could just generate a macro variable with the list of old=new pairs.

```
proc sql noprint;
%let renames=;
  select catx('=',nliteral(name),nliteral(substr(name,6)))
    into :renames separated by ' '
  from contents
  where lowcase(substr(name,1,5))='shoe.'
  ;
quit;
```

Then use that list in a RENAME statement. Either in making a new dataset.

```
data want;
  set have;
  rename &renames;
run;
```

or by using PROC DATASETS to modify the names in the existing dataset.